# Flask WTForm as response to a AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

In a Flask application, I am trying to "render" different Flask-WTForms based on various button choices. I also need to change the inner HTML of my div and hence trying to pass both the innerHTML and form together as below. I get a error that forms are not JSON serializable.

Any suggestions on how to do this on a AJAX call, rather than render a new page ?

Page is an object from the class described below.

```
@app.route('/_select_forms',methods=['GET','POST'])
def _creation_frame():
    content_requested=request.get_json()
    Page=Page_contribute_frame(content_requested)
    return jsonify(html=Page.html_string, form=Page.form)
```

```
class Page:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.html_string = None
        self.form = None
```

```
<div id=contribute-frame></div>
```

`````
function contribute_frame(e){
  var request_json = frame_identifier();
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/_contribute_frame',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data:request_json,
    success : function(data){
      $('#contribute-frame').html(data.html);
    },
    error : function (){
      $('#contribute-frame').html('Browser did not get a response. Check connection.');
    }
  });
}````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this in Flask by rendering string.

`return render_template_string(Page.html_string, form=Page.form)`